# File manager for Ghost CMS

Tags: content-management-system, file-management, ghost-blog, file-manager

I was searching for a WordPress alternative for blogging, that is how I found Ghost. The CMS was promising, easy to use and has a beautiful GUI.

However after some resourcing it occurred that ghost don't have it's own file manager, therefore reusing uploaded images, media etc. is not possible or at least not that easily. Storage management is crucial to me, hence cloud disk space is not for free.

I found a possible workaround. One can pass in external URL's during post creation, but this would require a file delivery service, one more thing to worry about.

My question, is there any ghost plugin or service that can cope with this task? In case none, could you suggest me a reliable file delivery service? Ultimately, a CMS which is not WordPress and have all the necessary features along with file management?